# How can I find out which process was stopped by RansomWhere?

Tags: macos, antimalware, ransomware

**Edit:** Since this question turned out to be off-topic here, I've [re-posted it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/246167/153510) to Ask Different.

I use [RansomWhere](https://objective-see.com/products/ransomwhere.html), a tool to protect from ransomware.

As far as I understand, RansomWhere just warns me whenever an app tries to encrypt data. It's up to the user to judge whether they trust a process or not. (And whether the application is one which *should* need to encrypt data.) The user is given the choice of `Allow` or `Terminate` each time there is a warning. It has warned me about several apps I trust and that I figure did need to encrypt data, and I have simply clicked `Allow`.

However, just now I got a warning about a process I don't know what was. The message said "is encrypting data", so I figuredd I had to hurry, so I just clicked `Terminate` immediately after seeing that I wasn't sure what the process actually was. After clicking `Terminate`, the dialogue box disappeared, and I heard nothing more from RansomWhere regarding the issue.

Now, I want to know what this process actually was and what was going on. I don't remember the details given in the message, just that I wasn't sure which process it was. I wish I would have taken a second to take a screenshot before pressing `Terminate`, but unfortunately, I didn't.

How can I find out which process this was and what was going on?

Comment: use RansomWhen?

Comment: this isn't about informations security - it's more an application usage question. migrate to superuser?

Comment: @JamesLu Not sure. Better ask the mods.

Comment: Have you checked in Console?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara How?

Comment: Open Console and search through the list and/or use the search feature. I don't know if such a log is kept.

Comment: @Fiksdal He's referring to the Mac application, Console

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Looking. What a long list. How do I find relevant entries?

Comment: Search for the string "ransomwhere" maybe. I rarely use Console.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Tried that. No results.

Comment: @Fiksdal just search for ransom or some other alias

Comment: @JamesLu Yes, have searched for ransom as well.

Comment: @Fiksdal contact support?

Comment: this is a question for the vendor - there might be data in the logs (if it keeps any)

Comment: @schroeder Thanks, I'll contact the developers and ask. If I get a response, is there a way I can share the answer with the community?

Comment: This is really a SuperUser-type question. You could ask and answer your own question there.

Comment: @schroeder [Done.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/246167/153510)